# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method while Debugging

Tags: java

[image]

I am trying to implement Circular Linked List and getting Exception while debugging "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method."

Can anyone please let me know why I am getting this exception.

```
    public int data;
    public Node head;

    public CLinkedList() {
        super();
    }

    public void append(int data){
        Node n = new Node(data);
        if(isEmpty()){
            head = n;
            n.setNext(head); // Here is the exception, but i am not getting why it is coming.
        }
        else{
            Node temp = head;
            while(temp.getNext() != head){
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            temp.setNext(n);
            n.setNext(head);
        }
    }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(null == head){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: There is no problem in the code as is, I run it and it works fine. maybe add the Node implementation. and add the resources you are using such as com.sun.jdi library

Comment: Please see above updated image, Thanks

Comment: when I implemented it it worked so your posted code is not the issue, but i implemented my own Node class, so please include your Node library path, and also maybe try implementing it yourself.

Comment: @Adi I got the issue, please find below answer.

Comment: Happy to see you managed, as i suspected it was an issue in the Node object

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue.

Exactly this code is working fine while executing, but while debugging it was giving me an exception because of the overridden toString() method in the Node class.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [data=" + data + ", next=" + next + "]";
    }
```

In Debug Mode

When we will mouseHover on the reference, internally it will call toString() method which we have overridden and will try to print, In this case, it is circular in nature, so it is throwing "InvocationException".